# Find first occurrence of X number of missing days in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a pilot log book organised by date starting in cell A3. First date is in 2006 and it progresses until yesterday. Only dates that have flight hours are logged. So any missing date can be assumed to be a "Day Off".

I need to find a way to find the most recent gap of 5 days off working backwards from TODAY() to a maximum of TODAY()-90 (I am not concerned about gaps more than 90 days from today). I need the formula to return the first date logged after the 5 days off. I cannot use macros.

Example of data assuming start in A3:

```
2016-11-01
2016-11-03
2016-11-04
**2016-11-05**
**2016-11-14**
2016-11-15
2016-11-16
2016-11-18
2016-11-19
2016-11-21
2016-11-23
```

Gap is bolded above - Answer I am looking for is 2016-11-14

Thank you very much

Comment: Okay... What have you tried so far? Update your question with evidence.

Comment: A quick solution: If the dates are in ascending order, oldest to latest going down then you could try this formula in B3 and copy down:
    =IF(A3-A2>=5,A3,"")
  This is not ideal as when new dates are added you will need to copy the formula down and will show for every date that has a gap of 5 or more days.

Answer (score 0):

With `myDates` being the range containing the dates, and being less than a full column, sorted ascending as you show, try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((OFFSET(myDates,1,0)-myDates)>=5),OFFSET(myDates,1,0))
```

If you want to ignore if the most recent gap was more than 90 days ago, just embed the above in an appropriate IF statement:

```
=IF((TODAY()-LOOKUP(2,1/((OFFSET(myDates,1,0)-myDates)>=5),OFFSET(myDates,1,0)))>90,"nothing in past 90 days",LOOKUP(2,1/((OFFSET(myDates,1,0)-myDates)>=5),OFFSET(myDates,1,0)))
```

Comment: I found my own solution that  appears to work:{=MAX(IF((Log!A4:A10000)-(Log!A3:A9999)>=5,INT(Log!A4:A1000),0)*IF((Log!A4:A10000)>=TODAY()-90,1,0))}